# Was the general plot of Space: Above and Beyond ever released?

Tags: space-above-and-beyond

The series was cancelled after only one season, and I remember reading somewhere online, a few years after it was cancelled, that the producers had written the whole plot for the series but couldn't release it to fans due to copyright issue or something similar.

Did they ever release it since then, or give any hints or explanation as to the real reason behind the events depicted in the series and what was planned for the future?

Comment: Lotsa interesting stuff here. Have a read and feel free to self-answer; http://retrophaseshift.com/2015/02/24/what-could-have-been-space-above-beyond-season-2/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The producers did have quite a lot of ideas on how to develop the series for the following seasons, but nothing was fully developed since they knew early on that the show wouldn't be renewed for a second season. More information [here](https://retrophaseshift.com/2015/02/24/what-could-have-been-space-above-beyond-season-2/). Thanks to Valorum for the link.

Here's the gist of it, in case the link goes dead:

> First and foremost, the finale wouldn’t have been as it was; had they known in advance they’d get another season, it wouldn’t have ended with nearly all the characters dead or in mortal danger. But even with the finale the way it ended up, there were plans to continue the story.
>
> Wong and Morgan stated that McQueen would’ve returned to Earth and had to face his new disabilities. His replacement would’ve been a woman, although there’s very little detail about her character.
>
> In a separate chat with McQueen’s actor James Morrison, he described McQueen’s season 2 arc as a “warrior without a war,” and part of his recovery would’ve meant accepting his new prosthetic leg, built off the same technology used to construct the Silicates. Having his former enemies now, in some way, a part of himself might have proven difficult to accept.
>
> Furthermore, exploration of Chig culture and a look at their society and homeworld would’ve been a big part of Space: Above & Beyond season 2. Stumbling upon the incubator planet was setup for this.
>
> All of the characters in danger at the series’ end would’ve had a way out, should the continuation (in whatever form it took) have deemed their survival important to the plot. Damphousse and Vansen would’ve been captured and taken to work in a brothel (either the same one, or a similar one, to the Bacchus ship). Wang, meanwhile, could have survived with some kind of escape pod, left in space in a really difficult spot.
>
> The WildCards as a whole would’ve had to face the music, being courtmartialed for leaking info to the enemy as an act of conscience. And in the end, their punishment is simply to be sent back to the front lines.
>
> By the end of the series, the war would end not with a climactic battle and overwhelming victory for the humans, but with a peace treaty that no one’s particularly happy with, having wasted years and millions of lives and countless resources, all for nothing. According to Morgan and Wong, the series would end with the surviving WildCards having a toast to fallen friends, a bittersweet note to drive home the senselessness of war.